# Problema al mostrar los datos de la base de datos en tabla html, consulta SQL errónea

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, mysqli

Tengo la tabla tblDetalle_Compras.

**Tabla tblDetalle_Compras**:

[image: Tabla tblDetalle_Compras]

Exactamente, necesito mostrar los productos pedidos cuyo campo ´estado_prod´ sea igual a 1
Hasta ahí bien, sin embargo los necesito mostrar la cantidad de estos en general, sin importar el campo ´numero_compra´

Algo así como:

[image: Resultado deseado]

Siendo la columna Cantidad donde debería ir la suma de las cantidad de TODOS los productos con ese mismo id (y que aparte su estado_prod sea 1)

Sin embargo el resultado es el siguiente.

[image: Resultado obtenido]

**CODIGO DONDE LISTO LOS DATOS**
``

```
    /* Connect To Database*/

require_once ("../conexion.php");
```

```
$action = (isset($_REQUEST['action'])&& $_REQUEST['action'] !=NULL)?$_REQUEST['action']:'';
if($action == 'ajax'){
    $query = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_REQUEST['query'], ENT_QUOTES)));
```

```
$tables="tblDetalle_Compras";
$campos="*";
$sWhere=" tblDetalle_Compras.numero_compra LIKE '%".$query."%' AND tblDetalle_Compras.estado_prod = '1'";
$sWhere.=" order by tblDetalle_Compras.id_detalle";


include 'pagination.php'; //include pagination file
//pagination variables
$page = (isset($_REQUEST['page']) && !empty($_REQUEST['page']))?$_REQUEST['page']:1;
$per_page = intval($_REQUEST['per_page']); //how much records you want to show
$adjacents  = 4; //gap between pages after number of adjacents
$offset = ($page - 1) * $per_page;
//Count the total number of row in your table*/
$count_query   = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT count(*) AS numrows FROM $tables where $sWhere ");
if ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($count_query)){$numrows = $row['numrows'];}
else {echo mysqli_error($con);}
$total_pages = ceil($numrows/$per_page);
//main query to fetch the data
$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT $campos FROM  $tables where $sWhere LIMIT $offset,$per_page");
//loop through fetched data
if ($numrows>0){

?>
    <div class="table-responsive"  style="font-size:11pt;">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover" style="font-size:11pt;" >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class='text-center' style="font-size:11pt;">Código</th>
                    <th class='text-center' style="font-size:11pt;">Producto</th>
                    <th class='text-center' style="font-size:11pt;">Gasto</th>
                    <th class='text-center' style="font-size:11pt;">Proveedor</th>
                    <th class='text-center' style="font-size:11pt;">Cantidad</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody> 
                    <?php 
                    $finales=0;
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){   
                        $id_detalle=$row['id_detalle'];
                        $numero_compra=$row['numero_compra'];
                        $id_producto=$row['id_producto'];

                        if(!empty($id_producto)){
                            $sql_codigo = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT codigo_producto FROM tblProductos WHERE id_producto = '$id_producto'");
                            $rw_codigo = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_codigo);
                            $codigo_producto1 = $rw_codigo['codigo_producto'];
                            $codigo_producto ="".strtoupper($codigo_producto1);
                        }else{$codigo_producto='';}

                        if(!empty($id_producto)){
                            $sql_nombre = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT nombre_producto FROM tblProductos WHERE id_producto = '$id_producto'");
                            $rw_nombre = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_nombre);
                            $nombres = $rw_nombre['nombre_producto'];
                            $nombre_producto ="".strtoupper($nombres);
                        }else{$nombre_producto='';}



                        if(!empty($numero_compra)){
                            $sql_gasto = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT idTipoGasto FROM tblCompras WHERE numero_compra = '$numero_compra'");
                            $rw_gasto = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_gasto);
                            $idTipoGasto = $rw_gasto['idTipoGasto'];
                        }else{$idTipoGasto='';}

                        if(!empty($idTipoGasto)){
                            $sql_tipo_gasto = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT tipoGasto FROM tipoGasto WHERE idTipoGasto = '$idTipoGasto'");
                            $rw_tipoGasto = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_tipo_gasto);
                            $tipoGastos = $rw_tipoGasto['tipoGasto'];
                            $tipoGasto ="".strtoupper($tipoGastos);
                        }else{$tipoGasto='';}

                        if(!empty($numero_compra)){
                            $sql_idDepartamento = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT idDepartamento FROM tblCompras WHERE numero_compra = '$numero_compra'");
                            $rw_idDepartamento = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_idDepartamento);
                            $idDepartamento = $rw_idDepartamento['idDepartamento'];
                        }else{$idDepartamento='';}

                        if(!empty($idDepartamento)){
                            $sql_departamento = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT departamento FROM departamento WHERE idDepartamento = '$idDepartamento'");
                            $rw_departamento = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_departamento);
                            $departamento1 = $rw_departamento['departamento'];
                            $departamento ="".strtoupper($departamento1);
                        }else{$departamento='';}


                        if(!empty($numero_compra)){
                            $sql_id_proveedor = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT id_proveedor FROM tblCompras WHERE numero_compra = '$numero_compra'");
                            $rw_id_proveedor = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_id_proveedor);
                            $id_proveedor = $rw_id_proveedor['id_proveedor'];
                        }else{$id_proveedor='';}

                        if(!empty($id_proveedor)){
                            $sql_proveedor = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT nombre_proveedor FROM tblProveedores WHERE id_proveedor = '$id_proveedor'");
                            $rw_proveedor = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_proveedor);
                            $proveedor1 = $rw_proveedor['nombre_proveedor'];
                            $proveedor ="".strtoupper($proveedor1);
                        }else{$proveedor='';}

                        if(!empty($id_producto)){
                            $sql_cantidad = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT DISTINCT SUM(cant_reciba) AS cantidadTotal FROM tlbDetalle_Compras WHERE id_producto = '$id_producto'");
                            $rw_cantidad = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_cantidad);
                            $cantidad = $rw_cantidad['cantidadTotal'];
                        }else{$cantidad='';}

                        $finales++;
                        ?>  

                    <tr class="<?php echo $text_class;?>" style="font-size:11pt;">
                        <td class='text-center' style="font-size:11pt;"><?php echo $codigo_producto;?></td>
                        <td class='text-center' style="font-size:11pt;"><?php echo $nombre_producto;?></td>
                        <td class='text-center' style="font-size:11pt;"><?php echo $tipoGasto;?></td>
                        <td class='text-center' style="font-size:11pt;"><?php echo $proveedor;?></td>
                        <td class='text-center' style="font-size:11pt;"><?php echo $cantidad;?></td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="#"  data-target="#editProductModal" class="edit" data-toggle="modal"

                             data-codigo_producto="<?php echo $codigo_producto?>"
                             data-nombre_producto="<?php echo $nombre_producto?>"
                             data-tipoGasto="<?php echo $tipoGasto?>"
                             data-id_proveedor="<?php echo $proveedor?>"
                             data-cantidad="<?php echo $cantidad?>"
                              data-id_detalle="<?php echo $id_detalle; ?>">


                              <a style="font-size:11pt;" href="#editProductModal" class="edit" data-toggle="modal" data-id_detalle="<?php echo $id_detalle;?>"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar">&#xE254;</i></a>
                              <a style="font-size:11pt;" href="#deleteProductModal" class="delete" data-toggle="modal" data-id_detalle="<?php echo $id_detalle;?>"><i class="material-icons" data-toggle="tooltip"     title="Eliminar">&#xE872;</i></a>


                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php }?>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan='6'  style="font-size:11pt;"> 
                            <?php 
                                $inicios=$offset+1;
                                $finales+=$inicios -1;
                                echo "Mostrando $inicios al $finales de $numrows registros";
                                echo paginate( $page, $total_pages, $adjacents);
                            ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </tbody>            
        </table>
    </div>  
<?php   
}    }?>
```

¿cuales son los errores en la consulta?

Comment: Eso pasa cuando la consulta que estas enviando falla. `mysqli_fetch_array()` esta esperando un objeto iterable, sin embargo le estas pasando un `boolean` eso por que `mysqli_query()` falló, o sea, la consulta está mal construida. Intenta separando la query e imprimela para que la pruebes en `phpmyadmin`